# I open process window from within the main window, I want to be focus also from the main fram

Tags: c#

I open process window from within the main window,  I want to be focus also from the main fram. now the focus enable only in the process window

Comment: Do you mean both windows able to receive focus at the same time? Or that the 'parent' window is blocked because the new window has focus?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the .CreateNoWindow and .WindowStyle properties of the ProcessStartInfo class.

Comment: but I need to see the process windows